# How to setup Varnish logging on Linux Alpine?

Tags: varnish, alpine-linux

I'm aware Varnish logging isn't enabled by default and that it is enabled via `varnishncsa`, there are many articles online on how to set it up but not with Linux Alpine. I see [configurations for it here](https://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/aports/tree/main/varnish?h=master). But not sure any logging service runs by default.

Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable informative logs you need to start the following command:

```
/usr/bin/varnishncsa -q 'ReqURL ne "<url_which_should_be_not_logged>"' -F '%{Host}i %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\" \"%{Varnish:hitmiss}x\"' -w /path/to/log_file
```

after `varnishd` is started:

```
/usr/sbin/varnishd -s malloc,128M -a :80 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

If we are talking about an Alpine in docker container, just create the following `entrypoint.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /var/lib/varnish/`hostname` && chown nobody /var/lib/varnish/`hostname`
/usr/sbin/varnishd -s malloc,128M -a :80 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl

/usr/bin/varnishncsa -q 'ReqURL ne "<url_which_should_be_not_logged>"' -F '%{Host}i %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\" \"%{Varnish:hitmiss}x\"'
```

and place it to the end of the `Dockerfile`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Legend, you even gave me a docker example! Thanks man will test this out, where will the log file be available from, I assume /var/log/varnish ?

Comment: You can define log file path when start `varnishncsa`. It is `-w` key. If we are talking about alpine docker container, log is written to stdout inside container, so we can see it when check container's logs by `docker logs <container_name_or_id>`